# Declarative pipeline step for waiting for process to finish in order to mark stage as completed

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

Using declarative pipeline, how could i mark an stage completed based on a given condition?

For the following example, I want to mark the stage as completed when there's no processes running.

This example will be applied for checking when a given application is not running after a soft kill in order to proceed with the deployment

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('1') {
            steps {
                timeout(time: 10, unit: 'MINUTES') {
                    waitUntil {
                        script {
                            def ret = sh script: 'ps ux | grep testout.sh  | grep -v grep | wc -l', returnStdout: true
                            echo ret
                            if (ret != 0) {
                                // what should i use to finish this step?
                            }
                        }                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there's a better way to do this, but currently I'm achieving de desired result with:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('1') {
            steps {
                timeout(time: 10, unit: 'MINUTES') {
                    script {
                        waitUntil {
                            def ret = sh script: 'ps ux | grep testout.sh  | grep -v grep | wc -l', returnStdout: true
                            if (ret.trim() != "0" ) {
                                return false
                            } else {
                                return true
                            }                            
                        }

                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the meantime, if I find proper solution for this i'll update this answer.